# Metamask: This transaction is expected to fail

Tags: solidity

I have an ERC721 contract and i'm getting an error ('This transaction is expected to fail.) in Metamask with the following code:

```
event PropertyNftBought(address _owner, address _buyer, uint256 _price);

function buy(uint256 _id) external payable {
        price = price;
        require(price >= 2, 'This token is not for sale');
        require(msg.value >= price, 'Incorrect value');
        buildings[_id - 1].owner = ownerOf(_id);
        _transfer(owner, msg.sender, _id);
        payable(owner).transfer(msg.value); 

        emit PropertyNftBought(owner, msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
```

App.js

```
await landContract.methods.buy(_id).send(account[0], {from: account, value: '2000000000000000000'})
```

How would I fix this so that the transaction goes through?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why this transaction might fail. Here's what I could think of at the moment:

1. We don't know what the value of `price` is. If it's lower than 2, the transaction reverts.

   ```
   require(price >= 2, 'This token is not for sale');
   ```
2. According to the ERC-721 standard, if the token ID does not exist, the `ownerOf()` function throws an exception, which would in your case revert the transaction.

   ```
   ... = ownerOf(_id)
   ```
3. The `_transfer()` function might be failing. Possibly the `owner` (token sender) does not own this specific token ID, or is not allowed to transfer it by the token owner.

   ```
   _transfer(owner, msg.sender, _id);
   ```
4. The native transfer might fail if the `owner` (recipient) is a contract that has not implemented the `receive()` or `fallback()` functions, or has implemented them in a way that rejects the transfer.

   ```
   payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
   ```
5. Not sure if you're using an emulator or a live network. Some emulators have maximal default gas limit (e.g. 90k gas on Ganache) so if the transaction costs more gas units, you need to explicitly specify it in the JS function to override the default limit.